# How to append the same key in dictionary

Tags: python

I have below list of dictionaries

```
 _list = [
    { 'id': '1', 'contactName': 'John', 'contactEmail': 'John@abc.com', 'role': 'Developer' }, 
    { 'id': '2', 'contactName': 'Elon', 'contactEmail': 'Elon@abc.com', 'role': 'Developer' }, 
    { 'id': '3', 'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': 'Developer' }, 
    { 'id': '3', 'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': 'Tester' } 
]
```

Code is below. Can you tell me where the error

```
list_dict = {}
for element in _list:
    element_id = element.pop('id')
    element_role = element.pop('role')
    list_dict[element_id] = list_dict.get(emp_id, {})
    list_dict[element_id].update(element)
    list_dict[element_id]['role'] = list_dict[element_id].get('role', [])
    list_dict[element_id]['role'].append(element_role)
test = {'contacts': list_dict}
print(test)
```

My out is

```
{'contacts': {
    '1': {'contactName': 'John', 'contactEmail': 'John@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer']}, 
    '2': {'contactName': 'Elon', 'contactEmail': 'Elon@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer']}, 
    '3': {'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': ['Tester']}
}}
```

- Error is at role where role is not append, its every time append the last role
- Last dictionary should contain 'role': ['Developer','Tester'], my out is 'role': ['Tester']
- Basically role has to merged into a list

My expected out is

```
{'contacts': {
    '1': {'contactName': 'John', 'contactEmail': 'John@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer']}, 
    '2': {'contactName': 'Elon', 'contactEmail': 'Elon@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer']}, 
    '3': {'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer', 'Tester']}
}}
```

Comment: Is `_list` supposed to be a list of dictionaries?

Comment: yes @barmer, its list of dictionaries

Comment: Typo: `list_dict.get(emp_id, {})` should be `list_dict.get(element_id, {})`

Comment: You could also use `list_dict = defaultdict(dict)`, then you don't need that line at all.

Comment: Shouldn't `emp_id` in the code be `element_id`? I got a `NameError` when running the code in your question but after I change `emp_id` to `element_id`, the code gave output matched the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your input should be:

```
_list = [{ 'id': '1', 'contactName': 'John', 'contactEmail': 'John@abc.com', 'role': 'Developer' }, 
{ 'id': '2', 'contactName': 'Elon', 'contactEmail': 'Elon@abc.com', 'role': 'Developer' }, 
{ 'id': '3', 'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': 'Developer' }, 
{ 'id': '3', 'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': 'Tester' }]
```

I think you miss the left [.
And I tried this code

```
list_dict = {}
for element in _list:
        element_id = element.pop('id')
        element_role = element.pop('role')
        list_dict[element_id] = list_dict.get(element_id, {})
        list_dict[element_id].update(element)
        list_dict[element_id]['role'] = list_dict[element_id].get('role', [])
        list_dict[element_id]['role'].append(element_role)
test = {'contacts': list_dict}
print(test)
```

At the 3rd line in for loop, I replace "emp_id" in ur code with "element_id". So, it works. My result:

```
{"contacts": {'1': {'contactName': 'John', 'contactEmail': 'John@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer']}, '2': {'contactName': 'Elon', 'contactEmail': 'Elon@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer']}, '3': {'contactName': 'Suar', 'contactEmail': 'Suar@abc.com', 'role': ['Developer', 'Tester']}}}
```

Comment: As I said in a comment, this is just a typo. Don't waste time posting full answers for typos.

Comment: Ya, but I got the result that expected.

Comment: Of course, but the question should still be closed and deleted. It's not useful for anyone else.